# Thread is executing lines, but unaffective

Tags: ios, multithreading

Okay this is strange. I have a multi threaded app, thread calls back some method in the main view. I step through with the debugger, the lines are run, but nothing happens. Here is the flow:

I have AViewController, it invokes Wrapper class W with callbackTarget (AViewController self) and UpdateScreen Selector parameters. Class W opens the UIImagePickerController, grabs the image, and pass into an Image Processing (IP) class, passing along callbackTarget and Selector. IP class then spawns a thread to process the image. When this is done, the thread calls callbackTarget.Selector, which is to update the view with the results in AViewController.

I have a break point in UpdateScreen. All the lines are executed, but nothing happens on the screen. I am suspecting some variables are not visible across threads, but I don't know how to make it work. Help please?

**EDIT adding sample code. It's messy that's why I didn't include it to begin with**

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
    //    AViewController, this is entry point
        -(IBAction) callCardScanner_tapped{
            [testResultLabel setText:@"ocr started"]; // this is shown
            CardScaner* scanner = [[CardScaner alloc] init] ;
            [scanner scanWithCameraSendResultTo:self selector:@selector(updateScreenWithResultFromCardScanner:)];
            [scanner release];
        }

//this method is used to pass into the thread so it can call back
    -(void) updateScreenWithResultFromCardScanner:(OCRResult *)result{
    // ... update labels with result
    // ...
    [resultLabel setText: result.resultString]; // these lines seem to be executed by main thread according to debugger, but the screen remain blank
    }
```

**CardScanner wrapper class**

```
-(void) scanWithCameraSendResultTo:(NSObject*) target selector :(SEL) selector{
// ... 
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
        [rootViewController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:true];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
// ...
   ImageProcessor* recognizer = [[ImageProcessoralloc] init];
    [recognizer ocrImageInThread:img callbackTarget:callbackTarget selector:self.callbackMethod];
    [imagePicker release];
}
```

**Image Processor class**

```
    - (void) ocrImageInThread:(UIImage*) photo callbackTarget:(NSObject*) target selector:(SEL) selector{
        NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:photo, target, NSStringFromSelector(selector), nil];
        NSThread* ocrThread = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector: @selector(ocrImageThread_start:) object:args] autorelease];
        [ocrThread start];

    }

    -(void) ocrImageThread_start:(NSArray*) args{
    //.. do image processing to acquire result object, here in the end invoke the callback method
        [callbackTarget performSelectorOnMainThread:NSSelectorFromString(selector) withObject:resultObject waitUntilDone:NO];
         [resultObject release];
         [pool release];

}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: added sample code, please see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

After your processing is finished, you must update your view on the **main** thread. Most of UIKit isn't thread safe and is only guaranteed to work if you handle it on the main thread.

You can use `performSelectorOnMainThread` or the `dispatch_async` functions family to transfer the work back to the main thread.

Comment: the thread spawned in the image processing class calls performSelectorOnMainThread on the AViewController method

Comment: Are you sure everything that should happen on the main thread is really on the main thread? Are you closing the UIImagePickerController also on the main thread? As ChrisF mentioned, it would help if you post your code.